# desktop interface broken after recent update of 16.04

Tags: unity, launcher

I run 16.04 32bit and 64 bit on my computer. After normal update of the 64 bit OS the system launches gives me the login screen  then nothing other than the screen background image. No app launcher icons or file control or logout controls at the top of the screen. Have to hard reboot to shut down.
Problem only effects the desktop as I can launch apps from a terminal.
How do I get the desktop working again.

Comment: Mine is intermittent. Sometimes it boots normally, other times no launcher or menu bar / notifications.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from another thread, but my comments are below ....

My desktop was blank when I booted up Ubuntu 16.04 tonight. Wasn't sure what to do so right clicked and opened a terminal window from where I was able to follow the above two commands which appear to have fixed the problem. Thanks, much appreciated.

Just to repeat them from above .....

mv ~/.cache/compizconfig-1 ~/.cache/compizconfig-backup

setsid unity

Answer (score 0):

Proposal by Colin N did not work for me.

I found the following ugly work around:

1. reboot into recovery mode
2. choose failsafeX (I am being told my hardward is not recognized, so I

2.a ask to start with default settings by typing [tab] [tab] and [space] when the [ok] button is highlighted

2.b this makes start of X hang. So I press [ctrl]-[alt]-[f1] (which shows me the Xorg log) and then [ctrl]-c (which magically lets Xorg start-up continue).

3. I get a log-in screen and can log in as normal. Unity and X work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this occur 2 times recently.  I opened "Places" then "Desktop" and the Desktop appears and all re-boots thereafter work fine..

Strange!
Ken